# Angular - Não consigo exibir os dados da tabela

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Não entendo porque não exibe os dados da tabela, está idêntico ao da página que estava usando para estudar.

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="/lib/angular-1.4.8.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
            <p>Pesquise um menu</p>
            <p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
    </form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Preço</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="myTable">
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">
                        <td>{{ x }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.names = [
            'Jani',
            'Carl',
            'Margareth',
            'Hege',
            'Joe',
            'Gustav',
            'Birgit',
            'Mary',
            'Kai'
        ];
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Resultado :
[image: resultado]

Comment: Abra o console e veja qual o erro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem nada de errado com o código em si. Provavelmente o local do *script* do AngularJS não é **`/lib/angular-1.4.8.min.js`**.

O HTML está um pouco estranho, mas isso não impede o funcionamento da aplicação.

Tem uma abertura de `div` sobrando dentro do `form`. O HTML deveria ser mais parecido com o abaixo.

Veja o código funcionando usando um CDN.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.names = [
            'Jani',
            'Carl',
            'Margareth',
            'Hege',
            'Joe',
            'Gustav',
            'Birgit',
            'Mary',
            'Kai'
        ];
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
            <p>Pesquise um menu</p>
            <p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
    </form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Preço</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="myTable">
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">
                        <td>{{ x }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: muito bom, obrigado.. funcionou agora :)